# Install this web app bubble for safari mobile browser (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, installation

[image: screenshot of the bubble]

Do you have an idea what is this "Install this web app" bubble called? I want to know whats the name of that thing so I can research more about it.

Do you also have an idea on how to implement it? I need it to function exactly like the one on the image.

Any useful links related to it will be a great help.

Comment: Your image doesn't load

Comment: @lc. - Hmm, I can see the image loading properly.

Comment: Not sure. I've changed it to a SO image and it works now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [this](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) .

is very simple to use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/add2home.css">
<script type="application/javascript" src="path/to/add2home.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey @Joao, that was the exact plugin I'm looking for! Thanks! ;)